# How to keep track of thousands of painted shapes in Windows C++ CLR

Tags: c++, windows, controls, panel, paint

I want to have potentially thousands of painted shapes on a panel and be able to identify them when I mouseover or click on them. What is the best way to do this?

My guess is I have to have some shape regions in a table. And have some clever way of looking up matches when I hover across page. Seems computationally intensive. Are there methods out there that can help?

Comment: A small shape will be 10x10 pixels (smaller than that would be excessively hard to manipulate with a mouse). If you have thousands of those shapes, you're already looking at hundreds of thousands of pixels - roughly one entire monitor worth of pixels. I.e. the number sounds a bit high.

Comment: I was thinking about 16x16. I was thinking about having a scrolling panel. I belive I am limited to 32k in both x and y. Shapes will not overlap. That will give me at most 4.2 million shapes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you paint into your panel, also paint the shapes into a bitmap that isn't displayed and use the shape ID as the color. When you need to look up a shape, just check the pixel at the appropriate coordinates in your bitmap. Make sure you turn off any line smoothing or antialiasing when drawing the bitmap!

Answer (score 0):

What you want is something like a [Quad Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) or [Binary Space Partitioning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_space_partitioning)(BSP).

Quad Tree is fairly simple.  BSP's are insanely fast, but do not handle moving shapes and are difficult to build.

A [Spatial Hash](http://www.gamedev.net/reference/snippets/features/spatialHash/) is really easy to code and builds itself at runtime.  Its primary disadvantage is its worse case look up time degenerates `O(n)` (if most of the shapes in horizontal or vertical line).

[Box2D](http://www.box2d.org/) uses it own breed of [space partitioning](http://www.box2d.org/manual.html#_Toc258082970).  I'm not really sure what the underlying algorithm is and whether it's novel or derived.  But Erin wrote [Box2D's broadphase](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#ncwl7ziM06g/trunk/Box2D/Box2D/Collision/b2DynamicTree.h&d=4) so that it can be used outside of the physics engine.  The code is zlib licenced, so you can just copy out the few files you need.

Comment: Does windows have quad tree libraries? Or do I need to build them?

Comment: I don't of any standalone Quad Tree libraries.  However, Box2D's `b2DynamicTree` solves the same problem, (it could be QuadTree underneath).  You could link with Box2D's library or just include needed files in your program.